# 'Label' is not a valid named attribute argument in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin-studio

I have created an Xamarin Android app 6 month back and now I want to do some modification on it, but I am getting the errors mentioned below. Please let me know, why i am getting this error. is this the problem of different version on which I have created that app and version that I am using now.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
```

using Android.Widget;
    namespace XamarinAndroidApp
    {
     [Activity (Label = "About")]

**Error:**

1. 'Label' is not a valid named attribute argument. Named attribute arguments must be fields which are not readonly, static, or const, or read-write properties which are public and not static.

I am also getting error in following code:-

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
```

**Error:**

1. 'Theme ' is not a valid named attribute argument. Named attribute arguments must be fields which are not readonly, static, or const, or read-write properties which are public and not static.
2. 'Main Launcher' is not a valid named attribute argument. Named attribute arguments must be fields which are not readonly, static, or const, or read-write properties which are public and not static.
3. 'No History' is not a valid named attribute argument. Named attribute arguments must be fields which are not readonly, static, or const, or read-write properties which are public and not static.
   Please give me solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you updated all packeges you are using and try to `clean / rebuild` project

Comment: @Antav Kovalyov Xamarin Studio is up to date. I have cleaned and rebuild many times, but no benifit.